# How to set default content for WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm currently developing a gutenberg based WordPress theme but when installed into a blank WordPress install the user just gets a blank page.

When the theme is installed I want to automate the creation of some default pages with some default content in the form of gutenberg blocks, one for the homepage and a single but I can't find any official support for this. In addition I would also like to create some default categories and menus. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I understand that themes should't really contain default content but because gutenberg is relatively new I want to add content to make it easier for users to understand how to use the theme.

Answer (score 0):

```
$wp_insert_post_arr= array(
     'ID' =>0,
     'post_author'=>””,
     'post_date' =>””,
     'post_date_gmt' => “”,
     'post_content'=>”html in here…..”
     'post_content_filtered'=>””,
     'post_title'=>””
     'post_excerpt'=>””,
     'post_status'=>”draft”,
     'post_type'=>””
);


wp_insert_post( $wp_insert_post_arr );
```

You should search wp insert post rather than page. Pages are post types

I have deliberately not included a hook, there are activation hooks you can use, but you will also need to consider the following:

1. What happens if the theme is re-installed? I.e. pages will be created twice - need to control this somehow, generally a entry into the db is created to check
2. Post title - will it be unique in most circumstances?
3. If the user messes with the content, how can they return to the default?
4. I wouldn't code in homepage selection, it will drive users mad.